# Convert from mac address to hex string and vice versa - both python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, mac-address, dpkt

I have MAC address that I want to send to dpkt as raw data. 
dpkt package expect me to pass the data as hex stings.
So, assuming I have the following mac address:    `'00:de:34:ef:2e:f4'`, written as:    `'00de34ef2ef4'` and I want to encode in to something like    `'\x00\xdeU\xef.\xf4'` and the backward translation will provide the original data.

On Python 2, I found couple of ways to do that using    `encode('hex')` and decode('hex').
However this solution isn't working for Python 3.

I'm haveng some trouble finding a code-snippet to support that on both versions.

I'd appriciate help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`binascii` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) works on both Python 2 and 3:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.unhexlify('00de34ef2ef4') # to raw binary
b'\x00\xde4\xef.\xf4'
>>> binascii.hexlify(_) # and back to hex
b'00de34ef2ef4'
>>> _.decode('ascii') # as str in Python 3
'00de34ef2ef4'
```

Comment: Both solutions did the trick, thanks! I've chosen this one simply because I used     `binascii` for other methods in my code.

Answer (score 2):

On python3 encoding between arbitrary codecs must be done using the `codecs` module:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode(b'00de34ef2ef4', 'hex')
b'\x00\xde4\xef.\xf4'
>>> codecs.encode(b'\x00\xde4\xef.\xf4', 'hex')
b'00de34ef2ef4'
```

This will only work with `bytes`, not with `str` (unicode) objects. It will also work in python2.7, where `str` is `bytes` and the `b`-prefix does nothing.